# Merge multiple RecyclerView.Adapter for use with single RecyclerView (Android)

Tags: android, merge, adapter, android-recyclerview, commonsware-cwac

I have a json string which I break up into 4 datasets, each dataset has it's own RecyclerView.Adapter.

I want to output all adapters in the same RecyclerView ideally with StickyHeaders for each adapter.

I believe this can be done using ListViews via CommonsWare's CWAC-merge (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)

Any ideas as to how this can, or should be done with RecyclerView? I am an amature developer so the less abstract the response the better ;-D

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

in **new update** of Recyclerview widget you can use **[MergeAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/MergeAdapter)** class

```
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.MergeAdapter
```

instantiate adapters:

```
 private val mfirstAdapter = FirstAdapter()
 private val mSecondAdapter = SecondAdapter()

 // here is MergeAdapter class
 private val adapter = MergeAdapter(mfirstAdapter , mSecondAdapter )
```

and then usage:

```
 binding.recycler.adapter = adapter
```

how to update adapter: (using .submitList if use diffUtils, otherwise use notifyDataSetChaned())

```
  mfirstAdapter.submitList(myDataArrayList.subList(0, 10))
  mSecondAdapter.submitList(myDataArrayList.subList(10, list.size - 1))
```

Comment: MergeAdapter is renamed to ConcatAdapter since RecyclerView 1.2.0-alpha04:
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ConcatAdapter

Answer (score 1):

You achieve that with only one adapter: [SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter). With this library you can group your items into Sections and you can optionally add headers and/or footers to them.

First create a Section class to group your items:

```
class MySection extends StatelessSection {

    String title;
    List<String> list;

    public MySection(String title, List<String> list) {
        // call constructor with layout resources for this Section header, footer and items 
        super(R.layout.section_header, R.layout.section_item);

        this.title = title;
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentItemsTotal() {
        return list.size(); // number of items of this section
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getItemViewHolder(View view) {
        // return a custom instance of ViewHolder for the items of this section
        return new MyItemViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindItemViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyItemViewHolder itemHolder = (MyItemViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your view here
        itemHolder.tvItem.setText(list.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder getHeaderViewHolder(View view) {
        return new SimpleHeaderViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindHeaderViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        MyHeaderViewHolder headerHolder = (MyHeaderViewHolder) holder;

        // bind your header view here
        headerHolder.tvItem.setText(title);
    }

    public void addRow(String item) {
        this.list.add(item);
    }

}
```

Then you set up the RecyclerView with your Sections:

```
// Create an instance of SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter 
SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();

// Create your sections with the list of data
MySection section1 = new MySection("Header of section 1", section1List);
MySection section2 = new MySection("Header of section 2", section2List);

// Add your Sections to the adapter
sectionAdapter.addSection(section1);
sectionAdapter.addSection(section2);

// Set up your RecyclerView with the SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this library: https://github.com/martijnvdwoude/recycler-view-merge-adapter

Check the documentation on the Github page for examples on how to use this in your code.

Extract from the readme:

```
RecyclerView myRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

// Create new merge adapter
RecyclerViewMergeAdapter mergeAdapter = new RecyclerViewMergeAdapter();

// Add any number of subadapters to merge adapter
MyRecyclerViewSubAdapter subAdapter1 = new MyRecyclerViewSubAdapter();
MyRecyclerViewSubAdapter subAdapter2 = new MyRecyclerViewSubAdapter();

mergeAdapter.addAdapter(subAdapter1);
mergeAdapter.addAdapter(subAdapter2);

// Set merge adapter to RecyclerView
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(mergeAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [GroupAdapter](https://github.com/KyoSherlock/GroupAdapter)

```
GroupAdapter.Builder builder = new GroupAdapter.Builder();
builder.add(firstAdapter);
builder.add(secondAdapter);
GroupAdapter groupAdapter = builder.build();
recyclerView.setAdapter(groupAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a class that do exactly what u want
https://gist.github.com/agustindev/e2faa7ef6a7b61cc0eafeeaf81e4e434

```
    ...
    val multipleAdapter = MultipleAdapter()
    val adapter1 = object: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){ ... }
    val adapter2 = object: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){ ... }
    val adapter3 = object: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(){ ... }
    multipleAdapter.addAdapter(adapter1)
    multipleAdapter.addAdapter(adapter2)
    multipleAdapter.addAdapter(adapter3)

    recyclerView.adapter = multipleAdapter
```